# How replace the loops FOR and the IF condition with lambda expressions?

Tags: java, java-stream

The method takes in two parameters - a Map and a Set. Converts the Set to a List and starts looking for a match-a List item with a key in the Map.If a match occurs, it copies an element of the old Map to the new Map.

```
public Map<String, Boolean> getValidMap(Set<String> set, Map<String, Boolean> map) {
    Map<String, Boolean> validMap = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> mainList = new ArrayList<>(set);
    for (String listRule : mainList) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> mapRule : map.entrySet()) {
            if (listRule.equals(mapRule.getKey()))
                validMap.put(mapRule.getKey(), mapRule.getValue());
        }
    }
    return validMap;
}
```

I would like to replace the loops FOR and the IF condition with lambda expressions and streams.I am not familiar with streams and lambdas so I ask for help with this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you can stream the `Map` and then filter entries having the key in input `set` and finally collect those entries into `Map` and return it

```
return map.entrySet().stream()
   .filter(entry->set.contains(entry.getKey())
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a for directly from the Set and use computeIfPresent:

```
 public static Map<String, Boolean> getValidMap2(Set<String> set, Map<String, 
 Boolean> map) {
    Map<String, Boolean> validMap = new HashMap<>();
    set.forEach(s -> map.computeIfPresent(s, validMap::put));
    return validMap;
}
```